# "initWithTarget" a variable twice

Tags: objective-c

I have a viewController showing some content. In header file, I defined an instance variable named _clientRequest, which is a ClassA object. ClassA deals with downloading Json from server.

For different users, there are 1 or 2 places using ClassA in the controller.

Currently my codes are like this,

```
// 1st request. every user will do this.

_clientRequest = [ClassA alloc] initWithTarget......];

[_clientRequest download];

...

// 2nd request. some user will do this.

_clientRequest = [ClassA alloc] initWithTarget......];

[_clientRequest upload];
```

you may notice that _clientRequest "alloc" and "initWithTarget" twice. In the future, server request may be much more in this controller. So I don't want to declare 1 variable for 1 request. Is anything wrong in above codes? if a variable is alloc and initialized, how about re-alloc and re-initialize it? I run the app and no crash happens.

I am a newbie in obj-c. And English is not my native language. Hope you can understand.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This will leak memory** because you are allocing ClassA to _clientRequest, then allocing another instance of it without calling *release* on the first one. When you allocate data in this way, you must release it yourself.

You should call `[_clientRequest release];` before your second call to `[ClassA alloc]...`

Comment: Thanks. forget to say, my ClassA(a delegate) will launch an async request. if the controller is destroyed before ClassA returns, ClassA will cause a "send message to de-alloced instance" crash. To avoid this, I put [_clientRequest cancel] and [_clientRequest release] in dealloc method of controller.

Comment: if I put [_clientRequest release] before 2nd request, release in dealloc will cause crash(because some users won't have chance to make  2nd request, release 2 times). How can I avoid this?

Comment: When you call [_clientRequest release]; put _clientRequest = nil; after. Then in dealloc, put if(_clientRequest) [_clientRequest release];